# Same IP subdomains rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdomain

I have the following situation:
Both 'some.example.com' and 'other.example.com' are pointing to the same IP.
But I have to change 'some' to 'other', like if I access 'some.example.com' it would "redirect" me to 'other.example.com'. It's more like a rewrite than redirect.

I looked around google looking for some htaccess solutions, but no success.

Thanks!

Comment: It is unclear to me what you actually want to happen.

Comment: Sorry, let me try again:
'some.example.com' and 'other.example.com' are pointing to the same IP, they are basicaly the same website. But I want to rewrite 'some.example.com' to 'other.example.com' wheneven I access 'some.example.com'. I cant use a redirect because they are the same website.

Comment: If some.example should show the same content as other.example, I see no reason why you wouldn't use a redirect. If both subdomains don't point to the same folder on the server, it might actually be easier to do an external redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the DNS for both subdomains sorted out (e.g. you don't get a server-not-found error), this is how you do it:

First enable mod_rewrite on your server. Make sure mod_rewrite is in the right folder, and uncomment the corresponding entry in the config file. If you are in a shared host, this might already be done. Make sure `Options` allows `FollowSymLinks`. Again, if you are on a shared host, this might already be done, since you can't access the main config file in that case.

**If some.example.com points to it's own directory** add the following to a `.htaccess` file in the directory that points to:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s (off|on(s))
RewriteRule http%2://other.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

**If both subdomains point to the same directory**, add the following to a `.htaccess` in that directory:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^some\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s (off|on(s))
RewriteRule http%2://other.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

If you want more of a 'rewrite' instead of a 'redirect', replace the `R` flag with the `P` flag. Please note that this will cause some search engines to penalize your site in the search results, something you generally don't want.

Comment: The context is both subdomains pointing to the same directory, sorry I didn't mention that. 
I'll try this configuration! Thanks.

Comment: I've added a `\\` to escape a dot in the second code block.